# Python center string using format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting, string-formatting, python-3.2

I have a string called `message`.

```
message = "Hello, welcome!\nThis is some text that should be centered!"
```

And I'm trying to center it for a default Terminal window, i.e. of 80 width, with this statement:

```
print('{:^80}'.format(message))
```

Which prints:

```
           Hello, welcome!
This is some text that should be centered!
```

I'm expecting something like:

```
                                Hello, welcome!                                 
                   This is some text that should be centered!
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It worked very well for me, tested with Python 2.7.2 on Windows. You might want to actually *explain* your problem, saying that it "doesn't work" isn't enough.

Comment: Works on Python 3.2.3 on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: @unwind Pay close attention to how it's "centered" and you'll noticed that it isn't really centered.

Comment: The output of that for me is totally left justified.

Comment: @LevLevitsky I've updated the question to reflect what I believe the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You need to centre each line separately:

```
'\n'.join('{:^80}'.format(s) for s in message.split('\n'))
```

Comment: This works excellently, and handles multiple \ns, which was the problem with my original code.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative that will auto center your text based on the longest width.

```
def centerify(text, width=-1):
  lines = text.split('\n')
  width = max(map(len, lines)) if width == -1 else width
  return '\n'.join(line.center(width) for line in lines)

print(centerify("Hello, welcome!\nThis is some text that should be centered!"))
print(centerify("Hello, welcome!\nThis is some text that should be centered!", 80))
```

```html
<script src="//repl.it/embed/IUUa/4.js"></script>
```