# python print in center

Tags: python, macos, screenshot

Alright, I asked my question last time in a untimely manner, what I should have asked is how do I ***CENTER*** the question asked in the middle of the screen?
I included this screenshot last time, I want the question in the MIDDLE of the screen :D. Sorry. 
[image: Techhelp.img]

Thanks! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383244/python-centre-string-using-format-specifier) question, and maybe this snippet works for you?: http://www.aliendev.com/programming/snippet-friday-programming/quick-snippet-friday-center-text-in-a-console-python-program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using screen width detection from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/566746/how-to-get-console-window-width-in-python)

```
def center_print(s):
    import os,sys
    command = "mode con ^ | findstr Columns" if sys.platform == 'win32' else "stty size"
    ignore, columns = os.popen(command).read().split()
    print " "*((int(columns)-len(s))/2)+s

center_print("aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can define a special printing function like this:

```
terminal_width = 80  # Change this if necessary.

def center_print(s):
    print '{:^terminal_width}'.format(s)
```

And call it when you need output in the center. So call that function instead of `print` for your questions.

Comment: To be clear: this centers the message in the _expected_ width of the screen, not necessary the _actual_ width.